RxJava Iterate over list, call API for each item, and return a list as result?
I have to call an API which returns an object, and inside this object, there is a list.
For each item in this list, I have to retrieve item details. To retrieve details, I have to make async API calls as well.
In the end, I need to return the original object.
My code looks like this:
mDataRepository.getSearchResult(String.valueOf(searchQuery))
    .subscribeOn(SchedulerFactory.get().getContentScheduler())
    .filter(searchResultList - > searchResultList != null &&
        searchResultList.contents != null &&
        searchResultList.contents.list != null)
    .map(searchResultList - > {
        Arrays.stream(searchResultList.contents.list)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .forEach(contentItem - > {
            if (VLOG_TYPE == contentItem.type) {
                Vlog vlog = mDataRepository.getVlogInfo(contentItem.type)
                    .defaultIfEmpty(new Vlog())
                    .blockingFirst(); // has to go away
                contentItem.description = vlog.description;
            }
        });
        return searchResultList;
    });

I was asked to remove .blockingFirst(); and rework the logic.
The problem is that, I don't really know how to rework this because it's a chain of methods above and below this call.
Thoughts?

You can probably use a flatmap to retrieve the item details(do the async API call).
See this documentation for more details, here is an example.

I would re do this using flatmap something like this
mDataRepository.getSearchResult(String.valueOf(searchQuery))
.subscribeOn(SchedulerFactory.get().getContentScheduler())
.filter(searchResultList -> searchResultList != null &&
        searchResultList.contents != null &&
        searchResultList.contents.list != null)
.flatMap(searchResultList -> 
    Observable.fromIterable(searchResultList.contents.list) 
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .flatMap(contentItem -> {
            if (VLOG_TYPE == contentItem.type) {
                return mDataRepository.getVlogInfo(contentItem.type)
                    .defaultIfEmpty(new Vlog())
                    .map(vlog -> {
                        contentItem.description = vlog.description;
                        return contentItem; 
                    });
            } else {
                return Observable.just(contentItem); 
            }
        })
        .toList() 
        .map(list -> {
            searchResultList.contents.list = list;
            return searchResultList; 
        })
)
.observeOn(SchedulerFactory.get().getMainScheduler())

